How to get telnet output to a variable?
I have a Bash script which sends a value using telnet and receive some data back. How can I put the data I received into a variable?
Manually when I run the commands i get the following results.
$telnet 192.168.11 12345
>> 5 :234568
>>Adjust:False,offset 0

The first line is my input and the second line is the response I receive. I want to assign this response to a variable.
In the bash script I tried using,
    response=$(echo -e "$message" | telnet "$TELNET_SERVER" "$TELNET_PORT" 2>&1)
    echo "Response from server: $response"

while it managed to send the data ("message") successfully. I couldn't get the response assigned to a variable. While tried running the command in terminal, the output is empty.
Can anyone give me some solution? Thank you.

Telnet is finicky to automate. See if you can switch to nc et al.

Aside: If you really need the behavior of -e in echo -e "$message", use printf '%b\n' "$message" instead to avoid surprises. Even if your shell is 100% certain to be bash, echo -e can sometimes print -e on output instead of changing behavior in handling escape sequences; in more strictly POSIX-compliant shells, it'll do that 100% of the time.

telnet is designed for interactivity. Use nc, ncat, netcat or any other tool of this family. If you need a dialog, then socat is my recommendation.

You can use the TCP/IP stack of bash instead of telnet:
#!/bin/bash

TELNET_SERVER=192.168.1.1    # shall be an IP address (not a DNS)
TELNET_PORT=5000
message='5 :234568'

exec 3<>/dev/tcp/"$TELNET_SERVER"/"$TELNET_PORT"

echo -e "$message" >&3

IFS= read -r -u3 -t1 response

exec 3<&-

There's a few shortcomings with this method though:

If the response is expected to span multiple lines then you'll have to use a while read loop instead of just a single read.

If the response takes more time to arrive than the specified timeout (here it is -t 1 second) then the read will be aborted. I have to say that specifying a timeout is absolutely necessary; without it the read could hang indefinitely.



See edit below
Looks like you're simply trying to see if a port is open on a host, or making sure firewall is open via telnet. At first glance it looks like your attempts may have been waiting for an open telnet connection to close. Try it with forced close on successes, as in my examples below.
Here's what I tested and it works. You'll get different results for failures and successes. Here's my tests with variable contents:
Success (Checking if port open via telnet):
# telnet_output=$(echo close | telnet localhost 80)
Connection closed by foreign host.
# echo $telnet_output
 Escape character is '^]'.

Failure (Port not open):
# telnet_output=$(echo close | telnet localhost 6969)
telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
# echo $telnet_output
 Trying 127.0.0.1...

====== EDIT, Actual answer (I hope) ======
Sorry I misread your post, seems you're actually sending a command and wanting the ACTUAL response, here's what worked for me:
Success. Connect to telnet, send command, store response in variable, echo response:
# telnet_output=$({ echo "GET / HTTP/1.1"; echo "Host: localhost"; echo; sleep 1; } | telnet localhost 80)
Connection closed by foreign host.
# echo $telnet_output
 HTTP/1.1 302 Found Date: Wed, 15 May 2024 20:03:01 GMT Server: Apache Location: http://localhost/xxxx/Login.do Content-Length: 213 Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN"> <html><head> <title>302 Found</title> </head><body> <h1>Found</h1> <p>The document has moved <a href="http://localhost/xxxx/Login.do">here</a>.</p> </body></html>

Hope this helps :)
